# Checking a value in a database from Javascript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to check the value selected in a `<select>` dropdown and when I figure out how it works I want to hide a div depending on the result.

Javascript

```
<script>
    e = document.getElementById("category_name");
    e.addEventListener('change', checkDatabase);

    function checkDatabase(y) {
        var item = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        $.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/check',
            {
                _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
                data: {
                    check: item
                }}
        )

            .done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log('ERROR');
            });
    }

</script>
```

Route

```
Route::post('categories/check', ['uses' => 'CategoryController@check', 'as' => 'categories.check']);
```

Category Controller

```
 public function check(Request $request){
    $cal = Category::find($request->input('check'));
    return $cal->calibrated;
}
```

I have been trying to get this to work for hours and hours but keep getting this error

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/check 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   ERROR

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong

Comment: Check `laravel.log` (or others) in `storage/logs` to find out what's wrong.

Comment: No nothing relating to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing a POST to *retrieve* data?

Comment: Thought I'd need to post as I was passing to the controller the value selected in the drop down.  This is then used to find a value for that item in the database.

Comment: [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/basic) might help you determine what went wrong on the server.

Comment: If you are using Chrome browser check in the network tab the issue from your code I believe it's gonna be about CSRF token

Answer (score 0):

You should review your *storage/logs/laravel.log* file or the *response preview* at network tab in your browser inspector to know more about the error, but as far I can tell, it could be the combination of this **4** things:

**1.-** The most visible one is that you are sending through Javascript as (`data: { check: item }`), *(you can use `check:item` without enclosing it within the data object)*

But you are retriving `'check'` at your controller (`$request->input('check')`)

Without rewriting your javascript function, it should work if you retrive your value as

```
$request->input('data')['check']
```

**2.-** Be sure your Table id is the value you are retriving, if not, use instead:

```
$cal = Category::where('search_term_field_in_your_table','like',"%$request->input('data')['check']%")->first();
```

**3.-** Be sure to have your csrf-token meta tag in your view

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**4.-** Be sure to have your use Request line at the top of your Controller File

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```